# Fancybox with PHP readfile() img source

Tags: php, jquery, html, image-processing, fancybox

In an attempt to keep user images safe, I am storing them outside the webroot and calling upon them with an id check within an additional "image.php" script. The script reads as follows.

```
session_start();
require("scripts/sqlconnect.php"); 
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$img = $_GET['id'];
$img = stripslashes($img);
$img = strip_tags($img);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id='$id'");   
$salt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id'");
$salt = mysql_fetch_array($salt);
$salt = $salt['salt'];
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $imgfp = $row['filepath'];
    if(hash('sha256', $imgfp.$salt)==$img){
        $data = getimagesize($imgfp);
        if(!$data){
            header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
            die('The file you requested is not an image.');
        }
        header('Content-type: ' .$data['mime']);
        header('Content-length: ' .filesize($imgfp));
        readfile($imgfp);
    }
}
```

The problem I am running in to is utilizing FancyBox with such a script. When I link to these images (as shown below), the FancyBox fails to work and it just links directly to the image. Does anyone have experience with FancyBox or a similar script that would cater to this method for calling upon images?

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="'.$relgroup.'" href="image?id='.$photofp.'" title="'.$pinfo.'"><img class="tnail" src="'.$tnail.'" /></a>
```

The onload js added for FancyBox is this:

```
$(".fancybox")
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0,
        'scrolling' : 'no',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
            type: 'outside'
            },
        }
    });
```

Comment: why don't you just build the `<img>` tag with PHP and the data from database ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor If i build the `<img>` tag from the database, I'll be using hardlinks to images outside the webroot. Those are filepaths I do not want visible to users.

Comment: what does this `href="image?id='.$photofp.'"` render? in case it hasn't any image extension try adding `type:"image"` option

Comment: @JFK it renders the image in a new page. do you mean `type="image"` within the `<a>` bracket?

Comment: @JFK i added you suggestion as stated above and i'm still being redirected to a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out **with assistance from JFK** in comments above.

I created a new class `.fancyboximg` and added the image type to that class along with the original onload changes stated in opening post.

Images now open in the FancyBox as desired!

```
$(".fancyboximg")
.fancybox({
    'type' : 'image',
    padding : 0,
    'scrolling' : 'no',
    helpers : {
        title   : {
        type: 'outside'
        },
    }
});
```